# Add values from File Reader API to an array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code which uploads an image and gets the dimensions of the image. I am now trying to add those dimensions to an array. Here is my code

```
files_dropped: File[] = [];

  onSelect(event) {
    this.files_dropped.push(...event.addedFiles);
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.files_dropped.length; i++) {
      formData.append("file[]", this.files_dropped[i]);
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        const img = document.createElement("img") as HTMLImageElement;
        img.onload = () => {
          console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
        }
        img.src = reader.result as string;
      }, false);
      
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files_dropped[i]);
    }
  }
```

this.files_dropped looks like this if I console.log it out
[image]

So I am trying to take the values of `img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight` and push them to the [File] property like how we can see `name`, `size` etc but I am stuck here

Comment: Can you share the outout of what `console.log(this.files_dropped);` inside the first line of the `onSelect` method is?

Comment: @Enijar I added it in the question

Comment: Hmm, that's an odd error to get. Just to test, can you add `const ctx = this;` to the first time of the `onSelect` method and replace `this.` references with `ctx.`?

Comment: @Enijar yes I can do that but how would I then add it to the array?

I tried this `ctx.files_dropped[i].push(img.naturalWidth)` but I get `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'File'.`

Comment: Here is a stackblitz example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-mg6mrz

Comment: @skydev I don't see a problem with the code above. Are you sure it's failing? If so which line is failing ?

Comment: @Melchia please check my stackblitz on line 27. The commented out line is failing. I want to add the `img.naturalWidth` to the File array

Comment: You can't do that. File interface is not an array. You can't also create another attribute in File object. I suggest you add in your question the structure or an example of the output you want.